# Mongo DB: cross collection query (join style)

Tags: mongodb, join

I have a db with 2 collections: *users* and *pages*.

In my app each *user* can have 0 or more *pages*, each *page* belongs to 1 or more *users*.

Each user has a `pages` property consisting in an array of objects with the `id` (not the default `_id` field but a custom `id` coming from the social network I'm taking the page data from) of the page and a couple other page info.

Pages have a lot of props, one of which is `is_synced` (boolean).

I want to query for all the users with their own synced pages (I just want some properties of the page object, say `title`).

I tried a javascript function in the console `forEach`ing on the users to query their respective pages but it takes a lifetime to complete.

I have no indexes on my collections except for the default ones on the `_id` fields (don't know how to set/use them).

What approach would you suggest?

Should I make an index over the page custom `id` field? Should I save the needed page properties in the users collection too even if they are not needed for the application logic but only for administration purposes? Should I perform some form of aggregation (map/reduce or similar)?

**Update**

As suggested I'm adding a simplified version of my JSON models...

*User*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("555bd93562ed89ff43d792ce"),
    "facebook_data" : {
        profile: {
            id: "98765456789",
            displayName: "Some Name"
        },
        ...
        "pages" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "12345678909876",
                "title" : "My Awesome Page",
                ...
                "is_published" : true
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    },
    "ready" : true
}
```

*Page*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("556632b1cb44ccc10c59b82b"),
    "facebook_page_id" : "12345678909876",
    ...
    "is_synced" : true,
    ...
    "facebook_page_data" : {
        "id" : "12345678909876",
        "title" : "My Awesome Page",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

...and the (rough) function I'm using to retrieve the administration data I need...

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(user){ 
    var pages = []
    if(user.facebook_data.pages && user.facebook_data.pages.length) {
        var page_ids = user.facebook_data.pages.map(function (page) {
            return page.id
        })
        pages = db.pages.find({'facebook_page_id': {$in:page_ids}, 'is_synced': true})
        .map(function (page) {
            return page.facebook_page_data.title
        })
    }
    print([ user.facebook_data.profile.displayName || '', user.facebook_data.profile.id, pages.join(',') ].join(';')) 
})
```

Comment: presumably you need to find using the is_synced boolean so indexing that would be worth exploring. db.pages.createIndex( {is_synced: 1}) but what is your query...

Comment: perhaps add an example of your json model

Comment: @GabeRainbow: I added some example data and the function I'm using. I was thinking about adding an index on page.facebook_page_id rather than on is_synced... but not sure at all about how to properly use indexes